# Azure AD bearer token - Get User identifier

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.NET Core API secured using the AzureADBearer authentication method.

Following the example laid our here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore

Calls to the API are secured using a bearer token that is generated with ADAL.net with this method.

```
    private async Task<string> getToken()
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        string userObjectID = (User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"))?.Value;

        // Using ADAL.Net, get a bearer token to access the TodoListService
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AzureAdOptions.Settings.Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID, HttpContext.Session));
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(AzureAdOptions.Settings.ClientId, AzureAdOptions.Settings.ClientSecret);

        result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(AzureAdOptions.Settings.TodoListResourceId, credential);


        return result.AccessToken;
    }
```

However, when i look at the claims that the API receives.. there is no identifier that appears as being unique to the user. The Nameidentifier claim is identical for every user i generate the token for.

The objectid generated in the above code - is the only unique aspect in the generation of the token, and that doesn't seem to matter in the claims represented in the APIs de-construction of the token.

Any thoughts on how i can get any sort of user unique ID across to the API? That could be email, SID anything i can use..

Comment: Why have you commented out the line of code that might work? You are using an overload of AcquireTokenAsync() that will use purely the client credentials to authenticate.

Comment: That isnt an actual overload that works.. That overload is for AcquireTokenSilentAync() which requires a tokenchache.

Comment: Right, is there a problem with the token cache?

Comment: It returns an error saying there is no token cache.. when i use it

Comment: Okay? I see that you are configuring a token cache though? Maybe it is not finding a token in the cache? You'll want to make sure your cache is populated after login and that the data is stored properly.

Comment: Is there a way to generate a token - without a cache - that transmits identity still? That you are aware of.

Comment: Authorization Code flow for example, you can always get a token after a user logs in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `AccessToken` there is a claim with a key written `oid` or `Object ID`. It is an immutable GUID that uniquely identifies the user as an Azure Object.

Look at this decoded `JSON Web Token` example of a user token generated by `Azure AD` implicit grant flow for a `Single page application` using `MSAL.js`.

> Note: Some items were omitted and changed for privacy reasons.

```json
{
  "aud": "<app registration guid>"
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/v2.0",
  "iat": 1606857684,
  "nbf": 1606857684,
  "exp": 1606861584,
  "name": "developer",
  "oid": "<Object ID>",
  "preferred_username": "dev@foo.bar",
  "sub": "RePapB10ksij8FA7dv-GdO9u4tz0_Hm4mmSeuGcqByY",
  "tid": "<tenant id>"
  "ver": "2.0"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - that would of done it!